# Handeling pthread Macro Error at Build Time?

Tags: c++, ubuntu, clion, cmakelists-options

I have been encountering same error for a large period of time now. C++ example below is simplified, as my first encounter with this error was while I was building a newly downloaded library. I don't know how to approach the issue. I have redownloaded g++, gcc, essential build and libc6.

Here a basic C++ code to demonstrate error:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <pthread.h>

int main() {
    pthread_mutex_t m = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

    pthread_mutex_destroy(&m);

    std::cout << "Hello, World!" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Following is CMakeLists.txt file:

```
project(clion_pthread)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

# Find the Threads package (this finds pthreads on UNIX)
find_package(Threads REQUIRED)

# Add your executable
add_executable(clion_pthread main.cpp)

# Link the executable to the Threads library
target_link_libraries(clion_pthread Threads::Threads)
```

**Error**

```
clion_pthread/cmake-build-debug --target clion_pthread -- -j 6
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/clion_pthread.dir/main.cpp.o
In file included from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/9/bits/gthr-default.h:35,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/9/bits/gthr.h:148,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/ext/atomicity.h:35,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/bits/ios_base.h:39,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/ios:42,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/iostream:39,
                 from /clion_pthread/main.cpp:1:
clion_pthread/main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
clion_pthread/main.cpp:5:25: error: ‘__PTHREAD_SPINS’ was not declared in this scope
    5 |     pthread_mutex_t m = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
      |                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
make[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/clion_pthread.dir/build.make:76: CMakeFiles/clion_pthread.dir/main.cpp.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:83: CMakeFiles/clion_pthread.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:90: CMakeFiles/clion_pthread.dir/rule] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:124: clion_pthread] Error 2
```

**OS**

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
```

Comment: I'm also a bit confused since it seems you did it correctly, but, why use `pthread` in C++? You know you have C++ ways of managing threads, right?

Comment: Originally I was trying to build some library that I downloaded from git:
https://github.com/microsoft/SEAL. At build time I receive similar error to one I provided above. That's why I decided to test on a small example.

Comment: Are you even sure PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER is something you need to destroy?
Could be a static/global. But @TedLyngmo is right when writing new C++ code you should use std::thread (or C++20's std::jthread), and std::mutex/std::scoped_lock

Comment: Did you try **vcpkg** too? It must be easier than manual configuration. `pthread` dependency is odd on windows platforms, because windows is not a POSIX OS; and like many other API, it has its distinct threading API. Unless you are building on mingw or cygwin, you shouldn't see `pthread` in your code base.